# Why is current_user also available via @current_user with Devise?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

The [Devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) README doesn't mention anything about `@current_user`, and [I don't see any reference to it in Devise's source code](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/search?q=current_user) - nor in my app's source code (`grep -R "@current_user" app/`) - yet I am able to use `@current_user` in my controllers. Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create a Devise model, say `User`, then Devise generates a *helper method* for you dynamically, named `current_user`. This method returns the value of *instance variable* `@current_user`. By using `@current_user` you are just directly accessing the instance variable instead of via `current_user` method. So, you see why the values are the same.

In Devise, the implementation of the `current_#{mapping}` helper method is as below:

```
      def current_#{mapping}
        @current_#{mapping} ||= warden.authenticate(scope: :#{mapping})
      end
```

where `mapping` would be replaced by your *Devise model name*, which in your case is `user`.

Refer to **[current_#{mapping} method definition](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/b786c384d54a6365bdc6c0cf6068dc5325a301a9/lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb#LC57)** in Devise source code.

Comment: Do you know every documentation of every existing gem, Kirti? Because each time I see one of your answers you give the exact references in the documentation (which is great btw)!

Comment: @MrYoshiji Only the gems which I use :D

Comment: Im curious about the number of apps you developped? You seem to have a very nice variety of knowledge about Ruby, Rails and the popular gems!

Comment: @MrYoshiji I am a recent convert from Java to Ruby. A curious noob you can say. Not many apps in Ruby/ Rails but definitely working towards it.

Comment: Would you go back to java one day? I've never liked Java... Too many type cast!

Comment: Thank you, @KirtiThorat. Do you by chance know where/when `current_#{mapping}` is automatically executed? What I mean is that if I can exclusively call `@current_user`, without first calling `current_user`, then that means `current_user` must have already been called beforehand (by Devise) - so as to set `@current_user`. And if that is the case then technically it is advantageous to use `@current_user` exclusively, as it saves a method call and comparison. Albeit a nominal "optimization", but one nonetheless. Thoughts?